# cannot end session

Tags: node.js

I'm using socket.io and express and have the following code:

```
io.set('authorization', function (data, accept) {
if (data.headers.cookie) {
    data.cookie = parseCookie(data.headers.cookie);
    data.sessionID = data.cookie['express.sid'];
    data.sessionStore = session;
    session.get(data.sessionID, function (err, session) {
        if (err || !session) {
            accept('Error', false);
        } else {
            data.session = new msession(data, session);
            accept(null, true);
        }
    });
} else {
    return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
}
```

});

session is a global variable.

The problem is, I'm trying to end the session by calling session.destroy() when the logout page is called....but it's not ending. Is there anything additional I need to do?

Comment: That session global var is from Express right?

Comment: No, i added that myself.<br/>
var MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore;<br/>
session = new MemoryStore();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call `session.destroy(sid, [optional callback function]);` where sid is the session id. Here is the code for the Memory Store:

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/session/memory.js#L79-92

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work.
socket.on('logout', function() {
        console.log('Logging out: ' + socket.handshake.sessionID);
        session.destroy(socket.handshake.sessionID);
    });
Do I have to clear the cookie etc?

Comment: tried socket.handshake.sessionStore.destroy(socket.handshake.sessionID) but that did not work either. I'm using the session method for socket.io + express described here:http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/

Comment: You should try `sessionStore.destroy(socket.handshake.sessionID)` instead of `socket.handshake.sessionStore.destroy(socket.handshake.sessionID)`.

Comment: Tried that too, the session just wouldn't end.
console.log('Logging out: ' + socket.handshake.sessionID);
socket.handshake.sessionStore.destroy(socket.handshake.sessionID)
console.log('authenticated name username is: ' + session.authenticated_username);

Comment: do you know if I have to remove the cookie or close the socket too when I end the session? could that be why the session is not ending?

Comment: It looks like authorization is fired each time the browser is refreshed. I wonder if the browser is sending the cookie restarting the session again?

Comment: Each time the browser is refreshed the client reconnects to Socket.IO, so each time the auth is triggered, that's normal yes.